# How do I base a volume group name on the sytem's name in a cobbler kickstart template?

Tags: linux, kickstart, cobbler

We normally use `autopart` for patitioning. However, it's default sizing logic does not match our needs (we want to limit the size of the `home` logical volume).

When we try to manually partition the space (using `part`, `volgroup`, `logvol`) we run into the issue of not being able to make each volume group's name be based on the system (e.g., `vg_delta1`)

Does anyone have a solution for this? I initially thought we might be able to do template variables like so:

```
part pv.01 --size=1 --grow
volgroup vg_\$(name) pv.01
```

The problem is if the system's name had dashes and such. `autopart` deletes special characters. How do we imitate the same behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate the partitioning in the `%pre` section of your kickstart (which is simply a shell script).  Dump it into a file, and then `%include` the file at the appropriate point in your kickstart.  For example:

```
%include /tmp/disk.ks

%pre

cat > /tmp/disk.ks <<EOF
part pv.01 --size=1 --grow
volgroup vg_$(hostname) pv.01
EOF
```

Read more about `%include` [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#.25include).

Comment: Ahhhh smart. That way I could remove the special chars with shell tools. Thanks!